# Android how to fit a picture into progressBar

Tags: android, android-layout, progress-bar, android-progressbar

Here is my xml layout for my `progressBar`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/loading"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and here is the loading.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/picture">
    </item>
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="270"
            android:toDegrees="270">
            <shape
                android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5"
                android:shape="ring"
                android:thickness="3dp"
                android:useLevel="true"><!-- this line fixes the issue for lollipop api 21 -->
                <gradient
                    android:angle="0"
                    android:endColor="#007DD6"
                    android:startColor="#007DD6"
                    android:type="sweep"
                    android:useLevel="false" />
            </shape>

        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

as result I get: [image]

the progressBar radius is smaller than  the picture's. Is somebody know how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: have a Circular Image view in Layout of same Size as `progressBar` .

Comment: @ ADM, In this case I get just an image... without progressBar

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this -

**loading.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="270"
            android:toDegrees="270">
            <shape
                android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5"
                android:shape="ring"
                android:thickness="3dp"
                android:useLevel="true">
                <gradient
                    android:angle="0"
                    android:endColor="#007DD6"
                    android:startColor="#007DD6"
                    android:type="sweep"
                    android:useLevel="false"/>
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**And activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:gravity="center">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="100dp">
        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:indeterminate="false"
            android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/loading"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_background"/>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for  advice. but in this case I gate the same result...